# Redirect non-existing subdomains to directory of main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I currently use a number of subdomains for various projects but want to move these to a directory in my main site.

I want to delete these subdomains and redirect someone browsing to them to the new file location in my main site. To do this, I want to **redirect all non-existing subdomains** to a subdomain in my main site. **I don't want to redirect existing subdomains though**.

I currently have the following folder structure:

```
/
|---example.com (the main site)
|---blog.example.com (this subdomain will stay)
|---foo.example.com (example subdomain to move)
|---bar.example.com (as above)
...
```

And want to move the `foo` and `bar` directories to `example.com/projects/foo` and `example.com/projects/bar`.

So I will have:

```
/
|---example.com (the main site)
|    |---projects
|         |---foo
|         |---bar
|         ...
|
|---blog.example.com
...
```

I tried the following .htaccess in the root folder:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/projects/%1/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

But this only redirects existing subdomains; i.e. `blog.example.com` but not `foo.example.com`. Additionally, this redirects `sub.example.com` to `example.com/projects/sub/sub.example.com/` and not `example.com/projects/sub/` as expected.

I haven't much experience with .htaccess files so any help would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Does your apache config route sub/foo subdomains to the main domain? Or do they have their own vhost?